# 'error ()' Function in c++ is not working for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unhandled-exception

I'm new to programming concepts and using my first time working with such software like Visual Studio. So now I'm learning C++ language.
When I trying to deal with `error ()` function in C++ it gives me an error message saying **"Unhandled exception at 0x76DE3E28 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0116F8CC.**". Here is my code sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int area(int w , int l)
{
if (w <= 0 || l <= 0) error("There's something went wrong!");
    return w / l;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 0;
    cout << area(x, y) << endl;
    keep_window_open();
}
```

I've checked it many times and didn't find anything wrong with the code. Is there anything that I did wrong with that code? Please help me with this guys. It's much appreciate!!

Comment: Where is `error()` defined?

Comment: Bet the function does just that, throws an exception to abruptly end the program's execution.

Comment: It's not working because `"There's something went wrong!"` is grammatically incorrect.  That, and the fact that there's no such thing as [error()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html) - at least not as you're using it.  Also look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/79591/

Comment: The behavior you see is the correct one for this code. It's how your textbook's `error` is supposed to work. However, the code is a bit suspect. Ordinarily an area is computed by multiplying width and length, not by dividing width by length. Also, just remove the `keep_window_open()`. In Visual Studio run the program via Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of Bjarne Stroustrup's headers. If you looked at where the exception happened, you would see that an exception is being thrown. What you see is expected. You should not make assumptions about code you just get somewhere. Create your own error function and make it do what you are looking for.